# How to use where with relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have table properties and it have name, description,address,zip code.
I have relationship with district like this:

```
public function district()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Districts', 'id', 'district_id');
}
```

I have this method for search:

```
  if ($key == "search" && !empty($options['search'])) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$options['search'].'%')
                        ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$options['search'].'%')
                        ->orWhere('address', 'like', '%'.$options['search'].'%')
                        ->orWhere('zip_code', 'like', '%'.$options['search'].'%');
            }
```

Now what i want is to add is something like this:

```
  $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$options['search'].'%')
                        ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$options['search'].'%')
                        ->orWhere('address', 'like', '%'.$options['search'].'%')
                        ->orWhere('zip_code', 'like', '%'.$options['search'].'%')
                        ->orWhereHas('district',function($q) use($option_value){
                              $q->where('district','=',$option_value)
                              ->orWhere('district','=',$option_value);
                            });
```

Any suggestion how can i do this?

Comment: Exactly like you just showed.  `orWhereHas` is most likely exactly what you need and I see no problem with that syntax.  Is this not working?

Comment: I see...i checked again and i had some syntax problem...tnx